# How can i change the style of an input from controller ? CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to change the class of a field in a form in view from the CONTROLLER.

I have some field in example.ctp

```
echo $form->input(foo',array('label'=>'foo:'));
```

I want to change the class of this 'foo' from exampleController.php.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set class from controller

**Controller**

```
$this->set('class_name', 'is_td');
```

**View**

```
echo $this->Form->input('foo.name', array('div' => $class_name));
```

This will generate

```
<div class="is_td">
    <label for="FooName">Name</label>
    <input name="data[foo][name]" type="text" value="" id="UserName" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this would break the MVC structure; as all presentation logic should go in the view.

You could do this however:

```
// controller
$this->set('foo', 'some_class');

// view
$this->Form->input('foo', array('class' => $foo));
```